# Is it possible to resize the theorem title parenthesis?

Tags: fontsize, theorems, brackets

I currently am declaring theorems as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[We have some title that has $Y^{\mathcal{T}}$]
Theorem goes here
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

But this results in superscripts being sized wrongly in comparison to the parenthesis.

[image]

What can I do to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: what do you want to change? It would be rather odd to make textual parens like this act like `\left \right` and even in math, the parenthesis wouldn't need to be much bigger.

Comment: I would like the parenthesis to be larger, since it looks unformatted.

Comment: it's your document, but honestly I would not do that.

Comment: also of course the output shown is not from the input posted, which makes the question harder than it need be to answer.